# Concatenate a list of vectors of strings in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

If I have:

```
(["aa=AA"] ["&"] ["bb=BB"] ["&"] ["cc=CC"])
```

how can I get:

```
"aa=AA&bb=BB&cc=CC"
```

is there a concatenate function available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` will "flatten" your nested sequence at one level:

```
(apply concat '(["aa=AA"] ["&"] ["bb=BB"] ["&"] ["cc=CC"]))
;; => ("aa=AA" "&" "bb=BB" "&" "cc=CC")
```

Then you can use `str` to concatenate the strings from the sequence:

```
(apply str '("aa=AA" "&" "bb=BB" "&" "cc=CC"))
;; => "aa=AA&bb=BB&cc=CC"
```

Combined into a function:

```
(defn concat-str [s]
  (->> s
    (apply concat)
    (apply str)))

(concat-str '(["aa=AA"] ["&"] ["bb=BB"] ["&"] ["cc=CC"]))
;; => "aa=AA&bb=BB&cc=CC"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may implement it as follows:

```
(def concatenate (comp (partial apply str) flatten))
```

and then:

```
user> (concatenate '(["aa=AA"] ["&"] ["bb=BB"] ["&"] ["cc=CC"]))
aa=AA&bb=BB&cc=CC
```

Answer (score 1):

just for fun:
you can also use `map` function's behaviour for this

```
user> (defn conc [items] (first (apply map str items)))
#'user/conc

user> (conc '(["aa=AA"] ["&"] ["bb=BB"] ["&"] ["cc=CC"]))
"aa=AA&bb=BB&cc=CC"
```